# Javascript (0 && 1)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to debug some JavaScript code related to Dojo localization, and I came across the following code in Dojo:

```
isXd = function(mid, contextRequire){
    return ( 0  &&  1 ) ?
        contextRequire.isXdUrl(require.toUrl(mid + ".js")) :
    true;
},
```

What is the purpose of the ternary operator here? It seems to me that `(0 && 1)` would always be `false` and that this function would always return `true`. Is this a browser compatibility thing?

Comment: I'd guess that it's generated code.

Comment: Definitely not a browser compatibility thing since all browsers handle that case in the same way. As @Pointy said, it was likely generated by some kind of tool.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. The original code doesn't have this as far as I can decipher it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>The source I've found differs a bit from your code, but the explanation should fit.</sup>

The original code can be found in **i18n.js** which is part of the *full source* package:

```
isXd = function(mid, contextRequire){
    return (has("dojo-sync-loader") && has("dojo-v1x-i18n-Api")) ?
        contextRequire.isXdUrl(require.toUrl(mid + ".js")) :
        true;
},
```

The same part in **i18n.js.uncompressed.js** included in the *release* package looks like this:

```
isXd = function(mid, contextRequire){
    return ( 1  &&  1 ) ?
        contextRequire.isXdUrl(require.toUrl(mid + ".js")) :
        true;
},
```

When you take a look at the *The Dojo Loader* section ["Options/Features"](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/loader/amd.html#options-features), you'll see that `dojo-sync-loader` has a default value `true`.

The documentation states:

> The first column is the Option/Feature as defined within the loader, the second options is whether this is a detected feature (via has.add()) or **if it is just an option and its default value**. With “unbuilt” source, all the features and options are available. **If the loader has been built, then some of these features may have been set as staticHasFeatures and not be configurable anymore.**

As `dojo-sync-loader` is a non-detectable feature, the likely replaced it in the built source.

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely the line.